# SSH IdentityFile not work on config but works thru command

Tags: ssh, solaris, sftp

I have an encryption gateway connecting over sFTP to ~500 vendors, all working fine thru ssh-key based authentication. However for a particular host, it simply does not. It turned out to have a very unique behaviour. I have created a specific key for this particular vendor, but...

- authorized_keys uploaded to destination box:

`sftp> put vendorXX.id_rsa.pub ./.ssh/authorized_keys
    Uploading vendorXX.id_rsa.pub to /.ssh/./authorized_keys
    sftp> ls -l
    drwxrwxrwx    2 user   FTP_root     1024 Mar 31 01:04 .
    drwxrwxrwx    7 user   FTP_root     1024 Aug 25  2014 ..
    -rw-------    1 user   FTP_root     1680 Apr  1 02:54 authorized_keys`

- the pair sets matches to each other:

`$ ssh-keygen -lf vendorXX.id_rsa
    2048 e7:64:53:21:2d:12:62:bb:13:99:1b:c4:dc:24:78:09 
    $ ssh-keygen -lf vendorXX.id_rsa.pub 
    2048 e7:64:53:21:2d:12:62:bb:13:99:1b:c4:dc:24:78:09`

- Key is specified on ssh config for given host:

`$ cat ~/.ssh/config | ggrep vendorxx –A2
    Host ftp.vendorxx.com
        PubkeyAuthentication yes
        IdentityFile ~/.ssh/vendorXX`

- And bada bim bada boom… When I try to connect, it uses the key but still fire the password challenge:

`$ sftp -v user@ftp.vendorxx.com 2>&1 | grep -i ident
    debug1: identity file /home/gtwadmin/.ssh/vendorXX.id_rsa type 1
    Password:`

However, if I explicit specify the identity on sftp command, it goes on:

`$ sftp -oIdentityFile=~/.ssh/vendorXX.id_rsa user@ftp.vendorxx.com 
    Connecting to ftp.vendorxx.com...
    sftp>`

Any insight on this? My source box is Solaris 10 and Sun_SSH_1.1.6, SSH protocols 1.5/2.0, OpenSSL 0x0090704f.